# second video does'nt play untill the first video is playing first

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I have two video files which I created dynamically:

```
$.each(data.reports, function(i, report) {
       var video = document.createElement("video");
       video.setAttribute('src', 'friday.mp4');
       video.setAttribute('type', 'video/mp4');
       document.getElementById("Data").appendChild(video);
       $('video').prop("controls", true);
       $('video').prop("width", 400);
})
```

and if I press the play button on the first video, everything works fine.
If I press the second video first (before I pressed the first video) it won't work till I 
press the first video.

Why the problem occures?
I tried to search the web but without success..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check this url http://jsfiddle.net/fmh055jn/ it is also dynamic, It is working fine. Check the generated html after javascript.

Comment: This is very weird... :O
So what can be the problem? why it doesn't work in my website? :(

Comment: share the site url .. if it is public

Answer (score 0):

You should either set the controls and width property out of the loop or set these by video.setAttribute call before appending into '#Data' div. $('video') is targeting all video elements, so calling inside loop is trying to make unnecessary and wrong multiple binding

$.each(data.reports, function(i, report) {

```
   var video = document.createElement("video");
   video.setAttribute('src', 'friday.mp4');
   video.setAttribute('type', 'video/mp4');
   document.getElementById("Data").appendChild(video);
```

});

$('video').prop("controls", true);

$('video').prop("width", 400);